# poll() doesn't seem to see events on an UDP socket

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I'm trying to write a web program, using `poll()`. I'm creating a `UDP` in a `struct pollfd` array, and then polling it. However, the `poll()` returns 0 every time, no matter how many times I send it a message. When I just call `recvfrom`, it works just fine. So here's my code:

Creating and binding the socket:

```
struct pollfd[2] fds;
// ...
fds[0].fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (fds[0].fd < 0)
    syserr("socket");
listen_address = { 0 };
listen_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
listen_address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
listen_address.sin_port = htons(m_port);
if (bind(
        fds[0].fd,
        (struct sockaddr*) &listen_address,
        (socklen_t) sizeof(listen_address)
        ) < 0)
    syserr("bind");
```

Now this works:

```
for (;;) {
    memset(buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE + 1);
    rval = recvfrom(
        fds[0].fd,
        buffer,
        BUF_SIZE,
        0,
        (struct sockaddr *) &respond_address,
        &rcva_len
        );
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

But this doesn't

```
finished = false;
do {
    fds[0].revents = fds[1].revents = 0;
    ret = poll(fds, 2, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("poll");
    } else if (ret == 0) {
        // the loop always enters here
    } else {
        // the loop never enters here,
        // even though I send messages to the socket
    }
} while (!finished);
```

For testing, I use a command like this

```
echo -n “foo” | nc -4u -w1 <host> <udp port>
```

I would appreciate some insight

Comment: Don't smap tags. This is C++, not C. And no, the language of the library's **source-code** does not matter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two critical problems with the way that you use `poll()`:

1. You must set the `revents` field, for each file descriptor, to indicate which events you are interested in, such as `POLLIN` and/or `POLLOUT`. Your code fails to set `revents` to anything.
2. The third parameter to `poll()` is the timeout setting. Which you are setting to 0. This means "check the file descriptors for whether or not any of the requested `events` have occured, but always return immediately in any case, and if no file descriptors have the requested events then return 0".

Which is the behavior you are seeing.

Instead of telling you what you need to set the third parameter to, in order to wait until any of the file descriptors's events have occured, I'll just refer you to `poll()`'s manual page. Reading manual pages is good. They explain everything.

In conclusion:

1. Initialize each file descriptor's `revents` parameter properly.
2. Pass the correct parameters to `poll()`, as described in its manual page. If you want `poll()` to wait indefinitely, until any of the passed file descriptors' requested events have occured, there's a specific value to do this. Look it up.
3. After `poll()` returns, check each file descriptor's `events` parameter to determine the file descriptor's status.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never felt too comfortable with the man pages. It mentions
`short  events   The input event flags (see below)`, but I hardly knew what that could mean until you explained it here

Comment: Well, you really need to figure out how be more "comfortable" reading manual pages. Learning how to read and understand technical specifications is a mandatory skill not just for every C++ developer, but for a developer of any language or IT skill. Just a suggestion. This is now a good opportunity for you: open poll's manual page, start reading, and don't stop until you understand every word of it. You'll end up rereading it a few times. It might take you a few hours, but it will be time well spent. Not just by learning poll(), but by learning how to read manual pages.

Comment: Of course you're right, I actually meant the linux man pages which happen to be written in a really specific way. I'd better get to my homework then. Thank you for the suggestions

Comment: "revents" and "events" are swapped. "events" is an input and "revents" is an output